# Path to private assets on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pem

I have a PEM file that should be stored somewhere in my Ruby on Rails web app, and be referenced from the `production.rb` config file with the path, as per below.

`APNS.pem  = '/path/to/pem/file`'

I want to keep this file private, so storing it in the assets folder is not a good idea. Where can I safely store it and what would be the path like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place it anywhere in your app outside of `public` and `assets` and it will be inaccessable from the web. Placing it in `config/` is a common option.

To build a path to the file, you would use `Rails.root.join('config/file.pem')`

Comment: Thanks! So saving it in the config folder and setting APNS.pem  = Rails.root.join('config/file.pem') would be correct?

Comment: @Arturo Well, assuming the file is called "file.pem".